# Why SparkSession.sql("set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=None") doesn't work?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I want to use regular-expression in SparkSession.sql, but it doesn't work whether i use :

`SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().config("hive.support.quoted.identifiers", None)`

or

`SparkSession.sql("set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=None")`.

Please tell me how to do it.

The code:

```py
ss = (pyspark.sql.SparkSession
      .builder
      .enableHiveSupport()          
      .config("hive.support.quoted.identifiers", None)
      .getOrCreate())                                         
#ss.sql("set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=None")
ss.sql("SELECT `(col)?+.+` FROM table")
```

program result:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`(col)?+.+`' given input columns: ... ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you try to enable the RegEx? By default this behavior is disabled so you need to set the below property to true before running a query with RegEx columns.

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true")
```